# Checkerboard Background Colors with CSS grid with even number of columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a css grid that has multiple rows, each with 6 columns.

I'd like to use CSS to alternate the background colors of each cell and vary it by row.

So the first (odd) row, all even cells will have a blue background and odd cells a black background.

The second (even) rows, all even cells will have a black background and odd cells an blue one.

I'm struggling to do this with CSS since all grid elements are siblings, so using `nth-child(odd)` produces columns of colors rather than staggered checkerboard.

I've included a pen if anyone wants to mess around.

I'd ideally like a pure CSS solution without adding a bunch of classes to the markup. However, I'm open to JS help if necessary.

https://codepen.io/qotsa42/pen/BaZWwMq

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>  
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>  
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code of 6 columns, you can see that you have a repeated pattern every 12 elements.
You can start from there *`:nth-child(12n)`* and offset the position from that  12th position for the other 6 .

example

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(12n + 2),
.box:nth-child(12n + 4),
.box:nth-child(12n + 6),
/* next row  of 6 */
.box:nth-child(12n + 7),
.box:nth-child(12n + 9),
.box:nth-child(12n + 11) {
  background-color: black;
}


/* demo */

.grid {
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```